# How to solve this linear equations using gauss jordan method?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve the linear equations in Gauss elimination method

$$2x+3y+z=1\\
x+y+z=3\\
3x+4y+2z=4$$

Comment: Do you know method ? If yes where are you stuck ?

Comment: when iterate I got the below

2 3 1 1
0 -1 1 5
0 -1 1 5

Comment: Maybe you have a look at the wikipedia article about this topic and try to get it from there. If you then still have problems, describe where. Or do you only want to get the complete solution with all steps without doing anything yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&3\\
2&3&1&1\\
3&4&2&4
\end{array}\right)\\\\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&3\\
0&1&-1&-5\\
0&1&-1&-5
\end{array}\right)\\\\
\begin{array}{ccc}
x&y&z
\end{array}\qquad\qquad\\
\left(\begin{array}{ccc|c}
1&1&1&3\\
0&1&-1&-5\\
0&0&0&0
\end{array}\right)
\end{align*}

Z is your free variable .continue from here .

Comment: here I got stuck, how to proceed then?

Comment: You have infinite solution s here .$y -z=-5$ . So $y = -5 + z $, Put $z =t$. And from first row get x in terms of t .so t will span your solution space

Comment: @JessicaGtb Please take a look at the markup to learn how to typeset such systems.

Comment: @AlexR sure i will

Comment: @user208897 Please take a look at my answer to get an explanation for what happened and what that means.

Comment: but the answer is given as x=0
y=-1
z=4

Comment: @user208897 please recheck your question

Comment: @user208897 The answer you give is _one_ possible solution, but there are _infinitely many_ solutions. Either this was on purpose or your teacher / textbook has an unintended error here wich makes the solution nonunique.

Comment: @user208897 when you put t=4 you will get solution you have mentioned .

Comment: thanks @jessica Gtb, when I use z=t I got soln x=8, y=-5 and z=0

Answer (score 1):

The system has no unique solution, because it's linearly dependent ($III = I+II$), this allows you to drop one equation (say $III$) and find a basis for the solution space, by putting the system into the form
$$\begin{align*}
x + a z & = b \\
y + c z & = d
\end{align*}$$
The solutions will then be of the form $(b - at, d-ct, t)$ where $t\in\mathbb R$ can be chosen.
**Hint**
Look at the equations $I - 2\cdot II$ and $I - 3 \cdot II$.

---

Pursuing the hint you will arrive at
$$\begin{align*}
x + 2z &= 8\\
y - z &= -5
\end{align*}$$
Thus for any $t\in\mathbb R$ the vector $(8-2t, -5+t,t)$ will solve your system. Chosing $t=4$ you get *one* possible of the *infinitely many* solutions, namely the one you provided,
$$(x,y,z) = (8-2\cdot 4, -5+4,4) = (0,-1,4)$$